# Incorrect value returned when tapping on ListView item

Tags: android

In my app, I have a ListView. I am using a FrameLayout on the rows so that I can go to a new activity depending of the user taps on the left half or right half of the row. I need to pass one of the TextView values from the row the user tapped on to the Intent.

I'm using the following method to handle the taps on the right side of the row:

```
public void goToCaptureBonus (View View) {
        String tappedBonus = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.bonusListCode)).getText().toString();
        Log.e(TAG,"goToCaptureBonus, tapped bonus = " + tappedBonus);
        Intent goToCaptureBonus = new Intent(this,captureBonus.class);
        goToCaptureBonus.putExtra("codeTapped",tappedBonus);
        startActivity(goToCaptureBonus);
    }
```

However I am not getting the right value passed through. For example, I can see 7 rows per page, but they all return the value from the first row. If I scroll down and tap again, I get a different value, but it is also not from the correct row.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My Adapter (as requested):

```
public class AppDataDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String TAG = "AppDataDBHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
    private static String DB_NAME ="appdata.db";
    private static String DB_TABLE = "Bonus_Data";
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;

    public AppDataDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null,DB_VERSION);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        Log.e(TAG,"Entered createDatabase");
        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!mDataBaseExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {
                //Copy the database from assets
                copyDataBase();
                Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
            } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }

    //See if DB exists in userspace
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        Log.e(TAG,"entered checkDatabase");
        File dbFile = new File(mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath());
        if (dbFile.exists()) return true;
        Log.e(TAG,"dbFile = true");
        File dbDir = dbFile.getParentFile();
        if (!dbDir.exists()) {
            Log.e(TAG,"dbFile = false");
            dbDir.mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Copy the database from assets to userspace
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream mInput;
        OutputStream mOutput;
        String outFileName = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();

        try {
            mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = mInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                mOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            mOutput.flush();
            mOutput.close();
            mInput.close();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            throw new Error("copyDatabase() Error");
        }
    }

    //Open the database, so we can query it
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_NAME;
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    public Cursor getAppDataFilteredBonuses() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT hMy as _id,* FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE sState = 'CA'", null);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor getAppDataTrophyRuns() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT hMy as _id,* FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE sTrophyGroup IS NOT NULL GROUP BY sTrophyGroup", null);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor getAppDataAllBonuses() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT hMy as _id,* FROM " + DB_TABLE + " ORDER BY sCode", null);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor getAppDataSelectedBonus(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String [] args={id};
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT hMy as _id,* FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE sCode = ? ORDER BY sCode", args);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor getAppDataListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT hMy as _id,* FROM " + DB_TABLE, null);
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close()
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: This is how I am populating the destination activities:

```
// Handle the appData DB.
        appDBHelper = new AppDataDBHelper(this);
        tappedBonusID = getIntent().getStringExtra("codeTapped");

        // Fetch Bonus Data from DB
        Cursor data = appDBHelper.getAppDataSelectedBonus(tappedBonusID);
        data.moveToFirst();
        String sCode = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex("sCode"));
        String sName = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex("sName"));
        String sCategory = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex("sCategory"));

        // Populate the view data values
        bonusCode = findViewById(R.id.bonusCode);
        bonusCode.setText(sCode);
        bonusName = findViewById(R.id.bonusName);
        bonusName.setText(sName);
        bonusCategory = findViewById(R.id.bonusCategory);
        bonusCategory.setText(sCategory);
```

Comment: Can you whole code of your adapter.

Comment: @VrushiPatel I have added it to my question

Comment: Is it adapter class? I think you have added the Sqlite database class here . Where are you showing the data using adapter? @DJFriar

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta It is pulling from a SQLite DB.My ListView is being populated via the following: `// Populate the ListView w/ all rows
        Cursor data = appDBHelper.getAppDataAllBonuses();
        listView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.bonus_list_row_item, data,
                new String[] {"sCode", "sName", "sCategory", "sCity", "sState"},
                new int[] {R.id.bonusListCode, R.id.bonusListName, R.id.bonusListCategory, R.id.bonusListCity, R.id.bonusListState}, 0));`

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta I think I know what you meant. I added to my question the code I use to populate the destination activity.

Comment: Hey thanks @DJFriar.My bad.